# Getting events to be dependent on the completion of another event

Tags: google-analytics

A part of my site generates a handful of events from the same action. The default for Google Analytics is to have the events run independently. However, one of the events needs to happen last. Is there a way to force an order of event completion or at the least have an event dependent on another event?

I have found no documentation on the subject. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Universal Analytics has [hit callbacks](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) , functions that are called when a tracking call is completed. You can at least try to nest event tracking calls within event hits

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',          // Required.
  'eventCategory': 'category',   // Required.
  'eventAction': 'action',      // Required.
  'eventLabel': 'label',
  'hitCallback': function() {
    ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',          // Required.
  'eventCategory': 'category',   // Required.
  'eventAction': 'action 2',      // Required.
  'eventLabel': 'label 2'
   });
 }
});
```

Untested, but judging from the documentation I don't see why this wouldn' work.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I like that it is a solution using GA configurations instead of going into JavaScript. I'm gong to try this

Answer (score 1):

Could you do a simple flag?

Event #1

```
var flag = false;

function eventOne(){
    ga('send', 'event', 'Event Chain', 'Trigger', 'First Event');
    flag = true;
}

function eventTwo(){
    if (flag) {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Event Chain', 'Trigger', 'Last Event');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way of doing that in Analytics. To implement this sort of behavior, you would have to design it yourself based on your requirements and/or application logic.

If you are implementing a website using JavaScript, you might be interested in using the [*q* library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), which could help you in creating and composing asynchronous promises in JavaScript.

Without going into too many details (because it might be out of the scope of your question), that could yield something like:

```js
Q.all([handleEventOne(), handlerEventTwo()]) // Wait for 2 handlers to complete
.done(function (values) { // Execute this callback once the 2 handlers have completed
    ga('send', 'event', 'Event Chain', 'Trigger', 'Last Event');
});
```